# Determine virtual server data use over multiple datastores

Tags: vmware-vsphere, datastore

We currently have a physical server running 3 virtual servers spread across 3 datastores – 2 of which are networked datastores and 1 of which is the local datastore.

One of the virtual servers has been shutdown and is split across all 3 datastores. We plan to move this shutdown server to an external backup, while moving the remaining two virtual servers onto the local datastore. I need to accurately determine where all of the virtual server’s files are to ensure the two remaining virtual servers will actually fit on the remaining datastore.

I’m new to VMWare and have tried to a few different ways to determine file sizes etc, but every time I try to verify my findings my numbers don’t match the used space as stated by either VMWare or the server themselves. So I'm not confident that the two virtual servers will fit on the remaining datastore.

Is there a way in either Windows or WMWare to see how much data each server is using on each datastore?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: I am unable to boot the server which has been shutdown.